# Android studio app side nav bar drawer item

Tags: android

Friends.

I'm Developing one app for website blog from scratch. The app shows content from web api. I want to show categories (like tech, seo, tips) in side nav bar. When a user press drawer item. Ex.SEO that should search for text "seo". I'm having search button in MainActivity. The search fragment can search and retrieve results. I just want to simplify searching with side nav drawer item.

**Simply What I Need:**
I want to show button with name like "SEO" in side nav bar and when a user clicks that it should search for 'seo' using search fragment that already exists on MainActivity's Action bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an asycntask, get the api call and display in the side bar.

Use onclick method to search what has been clicked and then display in the main window.